# Scala: make an implicit class accessible from classes injecting the class defining it

Tags: scala, implicit-class

I have an implicit class defined in a class injected in other classes like this

```
class A {
  implicit class B(s: String) {
    def b = ???
  }
}

class C(a: A) {}
```

Is there a way to access implicit class B (and in particular its method b) from the class C, without importing it explicitly? (Please note that class A could not be a trait since it also injects some classes.)

Comment: Is there an `@` missing somewhere?

Comment: Yes of course, I edit my question (guice does not change anything here anyway)

Comment: What's bad about `class C(a: A) { import a._ ; { val b = new B } }`? You obviously can use `B` right away, so what's the question?

Comment: And your code doesn't really compile by the way, because `B` needs exactly one argument in the constructor. But it doesn't change anything about the fact that `B` is visible in `C` as soon as you `import a._`.

Comment: Actually I don't even have to define val b = new B, but I'm wondering if there was a possibility to achieve it without importing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1** (import `a._`)

Well, yes, as already noted in the comments, from your requirements it is not obvious why you wouldn't just import `a._` in the body of `C`:

```
class A {
  implicit class B(arg: String) {
    def b: String = ???
  }
}

class C(a: A) { 
  import a._
  { 
    println("hello".b)
  }
}
```

This one line really doesn't hurt anyone.

If you still don't like it, then the problem might be elsewhere. Thus my second proposal.

---

**Solution 2** (separating typeclass-like `A`-interface from `.b`-syntax)

This other solution is less about the reduction of number of `import`s in your code, and it doesn't even keep class `B` inside `A`. But it might address another issue that you maybe just can't quite articulate: it separates the functionality provided by `A` from the syntax provided by `B`.

The structure of the following snippet is inspired by the design of the [Scala Cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) library, that follows a very clear policy with the implicit declarations, always separating the typeclass defintions from the syntax.

The main idea is that:

- Implementations of `AIntf` provide actual functionality
- `B` provides only some additional "pimp-my-library"-style methods

and that we want to keep these two things separate.

Here is how to separate them, thereby also avoiding `import a._` inside of `C`. First, you define the interface that describes the functionality provided by `A`:

```
  trait AIntf {
    def usefulOperationOnStrings(s: String): String
  }
```

Then you can implement it by a few different A`s:

```
  class A extends AIntf {
    def usefulOperationOnStrings(s: String): String = "<foo>" + s + "</foo>"
  }

  class A2 extends AIntf {
    def usefulOperationOnStrings(s: String): String = s.toUpperCase
  }
```

Note that the object `B` has disappeared from `A`. Instead, it is moved in a separate `syntax`-package, and renamed to `A_Ops`. The method `b` is also renamed to `a`:

```
  object syntax /* should be package, object only for script */ {
    object a {
      class A_Ops(wrapped: String, ai: AIntf) {
        def a: String = ai.usefulOperationOnStrings(wrapped)
      }
      implicit def everyStringHasAOps(s: String)(implicit ai: AIntf): A_Ops = {
        new A_Ops(s, ai)
      }
    }
  }
```

This is how you use it:

- You say in the imports that you want to refer to interface `A_Intf`
- You say in the imports that you want to use the syntax `syntax.a._`
- You declare the `a`-argument of `C` as implicit
- Then you can just use `"string".a` syntax inside `C` without further imports.

In code:

```
import myproject.AIntf
import myproject.syntax.a._

class C(implicit val a: AIntf) {
  {
    println("hello".a)
  }
}
```

Now the implementations of `AIntf` and the syntax `.a` become independent. You can inject `A2` instead of `A`. Or you can change the syntax from `"str".a` to `"str".somethingEntirelyDifferent`.

The full code snippet:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object myproject /* should be package, object only for script */ {

  trait AIntf {
    def usefulOperationOnStrings(s: String): String
  }

  object syntax /* should be package, object only for script */ {
    object a {
      class A_Ops(wrapped: String, ai: AIntf) {
        def a: String = ai.usefulOperationOnStrings(wrapped)
      }
      implicit def everyStringHasAOps(s: String)(implicit ai: AIntf): A_Ops = {
        new A_Ops(s, ai)
      }
    }
  }

  class A extends AIntf {
    def usefulOperationOnStrings(s: String): String = "<foo>" + s + "</foo>"
  }

  class A2 extends AIntf {
    def usefulOperationOnStrings(s: String): String = s.toUpperCase
  }
}



import myproject.AIntf
import myproject.syntax.a._

class C(implicit val a: AIntf) {
  {
    println("hello".a)
  }
}

val c1 = new C()(new myproject.A)
val c2 = new C()(new myproject.A2)

// prints:
// <foo>hello</foo>
// HELLO
```

Unfortunately, I have no clue what `guice` is going to do with an implicit argument, have not tried it yet. It might force you to write

```
class C @Inject()(val a: AIntf) {
  implicit aintf: AIntf = a
  ...
}
```

which then becomes longer then the simple `import` mentioned in the first part.

Answer (score 0):

as noted in comment, just `import a._`:

```
class A {
  implicit class B(s: String) {
    def b: String = "hello "+ s
  }
}
class C(a: A){
  import a._
  val hello = "world".b
}

val c = new C(new A)
c.hello // "hello world"
```